# Mapkit how i add multiple annotations......window based project

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new user of Iphone App.. i am implementing Mapkit and CoreLocation framework first time...

my Application run well..but

1)   i wants my current location on MAP load but it not fetch when i test my application on Simulator...

every time it select (united state...North America)...:(

2)...and what i do for multiple Annotations....? which delegate method i use for it....

I use code of two tutorials..... please tell me i am doing right....? or suggest me what i do....

Thanks in Advance...:)

i use window based project...

in my AppDelegate.m file....

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    mapViewController = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];

    [window addSubview:mapViewController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

in my ViewController.m file

```
// this method execute when user type value in textField and click on OK button...
- (IBAction) showAddress {
//Hide the keypad
    [addressField resignFirstResponder];

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.2;
    //span.latitudeDelta=28.38;
    //span.longitudeDelta=77.12;    

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self addressLocation];
    region.span=span;
    region.center=location;
    if(addAnnotation != nil) {
        [mapView removeAnnotation:addAnnotation];
        [addAnnotation release];
        addAnnotation = nil;
    }
    addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
    [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
    mapView.delegate = self;

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];
    //[mapView selectAnnotation:mLodgeAnnotation animated:YES];
}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                           [addressField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"the url string is %@",urlString);

    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    NSLog(@"locationString is %@",locationString);

    NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    NSLog(@"list items are %@",listItems);

    double latitude = 0.0;
    double longitude = 0.0;
    if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) 
    {
        latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }
    else {
        //Show error
    }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

    location.latitude = latitude;
    location.longitude = longitude;
    return location;
}

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];

    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //mapView.delegate = self;     

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];

    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`mapView.userLocation` will (eventually) have the correct user location.  This won't work in the simulator, but you can set a location via the simulator menus.

`viewForAnnotation:` will be called with a `MKUserLocation` annotation when the user location is found.  You don't specifically need to use `CLLocationManager` if you are tracking user location via a `MKMapView`, but it can give better granularity of data.

Comment: thanks alot.for giving your valuable time for my code... i wants to know... My programming approach is right? or i modify some code?

Comment: Needs some tidying up, and you will need to test on a device rather than in the simulator.  Otherwise, it looks ok.